# Permission error for opening file nodejs

Tags: node.js, permissions

I am using express-winston for logging. However, when I try to log out data, I keep getting `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'logs/app_log.log'`.

The only way around this is for me to run my app with the `sudo` command. Doe anyone now a way around this?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you do not read permission of your log file. There are 2 solution for this problem.

1. You can run your app with specific user which have read permission of file. like in your case you can its root(sudo).
2. You can change the permission of you log file using chmod command in linux. You can set 551 to access your file without run app from root user.

For more info you can check about chmod [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)